# How can I insert a jQuery plugin into PHP code?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I want to insert the jQuery plugin *[dropdown login form](http://thefinishedbox.com/freebies/scripts/jquery-dropdown-login/)* to make my website more pretty, but I am really confused where and how to insert jQuery into my code. For instance the following is my `index.php`:

```
<?php
    include ('book_fns.php');
    session_start();
    do_html_header("Welcome to Store");
    echo "<p>Please choose a category:</p>";

    // Get categories out of database
    $cat_array = get_categories();

    // Display as links to cat pages
    display_categories($cat_array);

    //If logged in as admin, show add, delete, edit cat links.
    if(isset($_SESSION['admin_user'])) {
        display_button("admin.php", "admin-menu", "Admin Menu");
    }
    do_html_footer();
?>
```

And I want to add the jQuery plugin to the top of my index page.

How do I insert this jQuery plugin?

Comment: When you don't tell anybody what `do_html_header()` and `display_categories()` do this is going to be hard to answer.

Comment: You can easily insert any JavaScript code into PHP as static text, but you cannot execute JavaScript without a JavaScript interpreter.

Comment: The tricky part is not how to insert, it's how to use it properly.

Answer (score 3):

Get it straight from the CDN. Paste this code on your page's HEAD :

```
<HTML>
   <HEAD>    
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   </HEAD>
</HTML>
```

Then utilize the library just as you would with your usual javascript code just  like this one:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      alert('Hey! I was called when the document finished loading.');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me by answering my question. I am voting for you. It's the most I can do here for you :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should echo the  tag to your index page like this:

```
echo "<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>"
```

Or you include an HTML/PHP file that contains jQuery script in the <head></head> tag

```
include('headScript.php');
```

Or you write a function that echo the <script></script> tag above:

```
echo $this->headScript("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js");

protected function headScript($src){
    return '<script type="text/javascript" src="$src"></script>';
}
```

Comment: Cross-Site Scripting alert.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just treat the JavaScript and jQuery code as you would HTML. The server reads the PHP code and the PHP code tells the server what to send to the browser, and the browser is what reads the jQuery and HTML.